# jQuery 3 alternative for e.pageX and e.pageY

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using a custom drag and drop multiselect. After I upgraded the jquery library to 3.3.1 the drag event stopped to work because of pageX and pageY functions which were removed ( https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-event-pagex-and-event-pagey-normalization-removed ).

The .drag function works, but the script calculates the position of the options and don't allow them to be dragged outside of the multiselect's div. So I need to be able to use .pageX and .pageY for any dom element.

Is there an alternative for these functions? Can I create the functions by myself? Can I copy some code from older jquery libraries and use it as a function?

Any help will be great, thanks.

Comment: *If native event don't have pageX/Y, these are calculated using clientLeft/clientTop.

If html element has border-width:10px like the example above, in a browser that doesn't support event.pageX/Y and correct clientTop/clientLeft, jQuery returns 10,10 as pageX/Y, when mouse is positioned at left-top-corner of body. In a browser that returns correct clientTop/clientLeft, jQuery returns 0,0 as pageX/Y.* - https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3092

Comment: Could you switch to `clientX` and `clientY`?

Comment: I tried but it wasn't accurate. I copy-pasted the pageX and pageY functions from jQuery 1.9.1 to jquery 3.3.1 and they work well. Now I have a custom jquery file. The advantage is that I can use pageX and pageY on my jQuery 3.3.3 without having to create new functions.